# Primefaces: dealing with redirection when onbeforeunload is active

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, onbeforeunload

I'm using JSF redirection in many places in my code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

The redirect is sent in response:

```
<partial-response>
    <redirect url="http://some/url"></redirect>
</partial-response>
```

The problem is, I have active onbeforeunload and the warning message is displayed when the redirect is processed:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return '${onbeforeunload}';
});
```

Is there a way to plug into the redirect processing mechanism and deactivate the onbeforeunload in that place? Or is there any JSF2/PrimeFaces pattern to deal with onbeforeunload in generic way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the redirect function `PrimeFaces.ajax.ResponseProcessor.doRedirect(a)` to remove *beforeunload* listeners before redirect. [jQuery.unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)